# XSLT 1.0 replacing tab character with a HTML element containing a tab

Tags: xslt-1.0

I've been bashing my head against XSLT character replacement with HTML elements to no avail and can't for the life of me figure out how to get XSLT to replace a tab with a span element containing a tab.

What I have within an XHTML document is a pre element that contains tab characters, and I found an XSLT string replace template function which I'm using to try to replace the tabs with tabs surrounded by spans:

```
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:pre">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">

            <xsl:variable name="BodyText"><span class="tabspan">&#x9;</span></xsl:variable>

            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'&#x9;'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$BodyText"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Replacement template function for XSLT 1.0 -->
    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="search"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $search)">
                <xsl:variable name="replace-next">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $search)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text, $search),$replace, $replace-next)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <span class="tabspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                </span>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

However, no matter how I change the code, the span elements are either missing in the output (if I try to assign it via an xsl:variable like above) or it doesn't properly convert the XML escaped characters representing the angular brackets

```
&gt;
&lt;
```

Despite bizarrely converting

```
&quot;
```

To a quotation mark. I'm admittedly confused and don't know enough about XSLT 1.0. XSLT 2.0, 3.0 and EXSLT are not an option due to the limitations of the converting system.

Comment: Your `replace` parameter contains a node-set (or rather a result tree fragment). You need to **copy** it to the output, not extract its string-value using `xsl:value-of`. Post a [mcve] if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Due to the complexity of the setup and the sensitive nature of the content, it is not possible for me to produce a 'minimal' reproducible example. Additionally, changing value-of to copy-of made no difference and the span elements were still missing.

Comment: In typical stack exchange fashion I'm not expecting any prompt or relevant assistance.

Comment: You seem very bitter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following **minimal** example:

**Input**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head/>
    <body>
    <p>This is an example.</p>
    <pre>Text before    text in the middle  text after</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:pre">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-tabs">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="replace-tabs">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&#9;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&#9;')"/>
            <span class="tabspan">
                <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            </span>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-tabs">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&#9;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head/>
  <body>
    <p>This is an example.</p>
    <pre>Text before<span class="tabspan">  </span>text in the middle<span class="tabspan"> </span>text after</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

To make this closer to your attempt:

```
<xsl:variable name="BodyText">
    <span class="tabspan">
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    </span>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:pre">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="'&#9;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$BodyText"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchString"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $searchString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $searchString)"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$replacement"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $searchString)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```